# How to cross compile FFTW3 for AArch64 (with NDK)?

Tags: android-ndk, configure, fftw

I have followed [this blog](http://blog.jimjh.com/compiling-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk-part-2.html) and I did succeed in cross compiling FFTW3 for ARM v7-A. However, when it came to AArch64, I always failed in C compiler check.

```
running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/bash /bin/bash ./configure --disable-shared

--enable-maintainer-mode  --host=arm-eabi --enable-single --enable-neon host_alias=arm-eabi CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -O2 -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp --sysroot=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-L/arch-arm/ -fPIE -pie -lm --no-create --no-recursion configure: WARNING: if you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.

    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c

checking whether build environment is sane... yes checking for

arm-eabi-strip... arm-linux-androideabi-strip checking for a

thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p checking for gawk... gawk

checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes checking whether to enable

maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes checking build system

type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu checking host system type...

arm-unknown-eabi checking for arm-eabi-gcc...

arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -O2 -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon

-mfloat-abi=softfp --sysroot=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-L/arch-arm/ -fPIE -pie -lm checking whether the C compiler works... no configure: error: in `$FFTW_ROOT': configure: error: C compiler cannot create

executables
```

Why did it check `CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc` instead of `$CC` I have set?
Is it because I misunderstood `--host` flag in configure? I set it to `--host=aarch64`

Comment: I have tried to set `--host=aarch64-eabi`. It did pass CC check. Then I came across another error. `aarch64-*-gcc` does not accept flag `-mfpu=neon`. I wondered where to remove this flag.

Comment: This does make sense, try `-mfpu=fp-armv8` instead. You can add this as `./configure ... CFLAGS="-mfpu=fp-armv8"`

Comment: @AlexCohn I get "error: unrecognized command line option '-mfpu=fp-armv8'".

Comment: but in your Q you set `CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc` while I would expect `CC=aarch64-linux-android-gcc`

Comment: @AlexCohn, in the first comment, I tried to set --host=aarch64-eabi. Here, CC=aarch64-linux-android-gcc. Then I passed the CC check, but I came across another error: aarch64-linux-android-gcc did not recognize -mfpu=neon. This [issue](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/issues/25)

Comment: this is the error when you run `./configure ... CFLAGS="-mfpu=fp-armv8" CC=aarch64-linux-android-gcc`?

Answer (score 1):

[FFTW3 bug 25](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/issues/25) can be worked around by adding a command-line argument to the configure script call:

`./configure .... NEON_CFLAGS=-D__ARM_NEON__`

This is because the condition that checks for `-mfpu=neon` is only if `NEON_CFLAGS` is not empty, and then code expects `__ARM_NEON__` to be set.

That said, there are other blockers down the road, because there is simply no Aarch64 SIMD support code available.
So, until there is, compiling FFTW3 in aarch64 mode is futile ;)